# iOS / iPadOS Safari fails to load images after page load

Tags: image, http, safari

After upgrading my iPad and Mac, Safari no longer correctly loads images on a site I'm developing. Images included in the original page source load properly, but images added to the HTML after page load (such as images displayed in a modal) do not load correctly.

When looking at the requests in the Web Inspector on my Mac, the error message provided is simply "An error occurred trying to load the resource", with no status code or response headers provided.

- The image I'm trying to load is hosted on the same domain and subdomain.
- Loading the image manually (navigating to the image URL directly in a separate tab) causes the image to be cached. Upon a reload of the original page, the image loads successfully from cache. This error only occurs if the image needs to be fetched from the server.
- Other desktop browsers (and Android) load these images without issues.
- Versions where this issue has been reproduced:

  - MacOS Big Sur 11.6, Safari Version 15.0 (16612.1.29.41.4, 16612)
  - iPadOS 14.8, Safari 14?
- **Edit:** Disabling cross-site tracking has no effect on the image loading (on mobile or desktop Safari)

Any ideas?

Comment: As a temporary workaround, I updated my application to load these images (but keep them hidden) on the initial page load, rather than loading them after a user interaction.